Предлоги ИЗО и ОТО
Есть ли еще подобные предлоги? Каков алгоритм выбора этих пердлогов

Есть еще такие группы (гласный о добавляется к предлогу, состоящему из одного согласного звука или оканчивающемуся на согласный):
к — ко, в — во, с — со, под — подо, над — надо, перед (пред) — передо (предо).
[И отдельная: о — об — обо.]
Алгоритм выбора такой "добавки" у каждой группы свой, особенный (в одном ответе — не расскажешь).
А сжато о добавлении гласного о к предлогу сказано в справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию.
